# Can't understand the IP-addressing

Tags: networking, ip-address

in IP-addressing for an example 25.34.12.56 is a class A ip address.But what is mean by 25.34.12.56/16 and what class IP address is that?

Comment: IP classes are dead, killed in 1995 by the RFCs for VLSM and CIDR. IP classes haven't been used in networking for a very long time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's "Classless Inter-domain Routing" format, CIDR and specifies both an address and the subnet bitmask.

The 16 means the most significant 16 bits of the bitmask are ones, which corresponds to a mask of 255.255.0.0,   so basically a class B

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classless_Inter-Domain_Routing

Answer (score 0):

It is an ipaddress of classless addressing.
16 is the subnet mask